# Proving cardinality of basis in Module theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

This is an exercise problem from Graduate Algebra written by Hungerford.

Let $K$ be a ring and $F$ a free $K$-module with a countably infinite basis $\{e_1, e_2, \ldots\}$.  Then $R=\hom_K(F,F)$ is a ring, called the endomorphism ring of $F$. Prove that for each positive integer $n$, the free left $R$-module $R$ has a basis of cardinality $n$; that is, as an $R$-module, $R\simeq R\oplus \cdots \oplus R$ for any finite number of summands.

I was thinking that to prove free left $R$-module has a basis of cardinality $n$, we first suppose it does not have a finite cardinality and draw a contradiction? However, I wasn't able to point out the contradiction. Should I approach differently? Any help would be very nice.

Edit: there is a hint in the book. $\{1_R\}$ is a basis of one element; $\{f_1,f_2\}$ is a basis of two elements, where $f_1(e_{2n})=e_n$, $f_1(e_{2n-1})=0$, $f_2(e_{2n})=0$ and $f_2(e_{2n-1})=e_n$. Note that for any $g\in R$, $g=g_1f_1+g_2f_2$ where $g_1(e_n)=g(e_{2n})$ and $g_2(e_n)=g(e_{2n-1})$.

Comment: You only need to show, that $R \cong R \oplus R$. Then the statement follows with induction. For this you can work with the hint: you only need to show, that $R \cong R\, f_1 \oplus R \, f_2$ and that $R \, f_i \cong R$.

Comment: @pyrogen Your comment is very helpful!  How do we prove $Rf_i\cong R$?When $i=1$, I see $R(e_{2n})=R(f_1(e_{2n}))=R(e_n).$ How does this shows $Rf_i\cong R$?

Comment: basically you have to show, that $R \to R f_i$ by $r \mapsto r \, f_i$ is an isomorphism. It is clear, that it is surjective. To show, that it is injective you have to show, that $r \, f_i = 0$ implies $r=0$. Look at $0 = (r \, f_1) (e_{2n})$.

Comment: Also you should not forget to show $R f_1 \cap R f_2 = (0)$.